# Folding regions in visual studio code v1.17 not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code v1.17 and I am doing development in pure javascript for chrome extension development. Visual studio code v1.17 supports region folding facility for javascript and several other languages.

So, I created one class inside one .js file and write getter setter methods inside it. like

```
//#region EmailObj

get EmailObj() {
    this._EmailObj = localStorage.getItem("CurrentEmail");
    try {
        this._EmailObj = JSON.parse(this._EmailObj);
    }
    catch(e) {
        this._EmailObj = null;
    }
    return this._EmailObj;
}

set EmailObj(newValue) {
    this._EmailObj = JSON.stringify(newValue);
    localStorage.setItem("CurrentEmail", this._EmailObj)
}
remove_EmailObj() {
    this._EmailObj = null;
    localStorage.removeItem("CurrentEmail");
}
//#endregion EmailObj
```

Now as per documentation stated at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_folding-regions. Plus (+) icon should be shown near #region and #endregion sections (so, I can show / hide particular region) but it is not showing there.

So, somebody help me that what I am missing here?

Comment: I copied/pasted your code and it works fine for me.  Are you sure you didn't change these settings from their defaults:    // Controls whether the editor has code folding enabled
  "editor.folding": true,

  // Controls whether the fold controls on the gutter are automatically hidden.
  "editor.showFoldingControls": "mouseover",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated VS code to 1.17.2 and its now working at my side.